# Change URL of application according to logged in user in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I have been working a spring boot project for a while now. I am accessing my app's login with local url like **`localhost:8080/XYZapp/login`** then after a successful login my url changes to `localhost:8080/XYZapp/authenticated` (which is my dashboard).

All this working fine but now I want my URL to change dynamically acc. to logged in user like `localhost:8080/XYZapp/abcCompany/authenticated`. This **abcCompany** should change every time according to loggedin user.

I have googled it on some references and on SO but could not found much luck.

Comment: you might be the *abcCompany* on successful authentication, get the value and redirect to URL. For more info you can add the related code

Comment: @PatelRomil can u please elaborate, how will it change the url. Also i can add my current authentication code in which i want to implement this.

Comment: @high_on_java implement `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and override `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method where you can redirect to any URL. And in your spring security configuration configure your handler as given `.formLogin().successHandler(yourHandler)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you will need to do.

The first has already been mentioned in the comments, which is to use an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```java
@Component
public TenantAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof MyUser) {
            MyUser user = (MyUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String uri = "/XYZapp/" + user.getTenantName() + "/authenticated";
            AuthenticationSuccessHandler handler =
                new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(uri);
            handler.onAuthenticationSuccess(handler);
        }

        // throw exception
    }
}
```

Which you can then wire in your DSL:

```
@Autowire
AuthenticationSuccessHandler tenantAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

// ...

http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .successHandler(this.tenantAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
```

Of course, you might consider caching the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instances so you aren't creating one for every single login.

Second, you'll likely need to be able to know the name of the tenant (e.g. `abcCompany`) based on the user that gets looked up.

So, you'll likely need [a custom `UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice) so that you can retrieve that extra information from your datastore:

```java
public class MyUser {
    String tenantName;

    // ...
}

// ...

@Component
public class MyUserUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails findUserByUsername(String username) {
        // query some backing store, Spring Data repository, etc.

        return myUser;
    }

    private static class MyUserUserDetails extends MyUser implements UserDetails {
        // ...
    }
}
```